# Fetching the SharePoint list details based on from date and to date column

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a list name as `Inventory Details` and in that list I have inserted all details.

Now I want to fetch and filter all details based on the `start date` and `end date`. How I will do that?

Comment: Through which object model are you trying to retrieve the details? or you wat it to be in View?

Comment: server object model

Comment: Use CAML query to filter item.

Answer (score 5):

You may use SPQuery to filter the items based on start and end date.

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(Int32.Parse(year), 1, 1);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(Int32.Parse(year), 12, 31);
SPQuery q = new SPQuery();
q.Query = "<Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='Date' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' Type='DateTime'>" + SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(startDate) + "</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name='Date' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' Type='DateTime'>" + SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(endDate) + "</Value></Leq></And></Where>";

SPListItemCollection allItem = library.GetItems(q);
```